# No background in SDL window after first launch

Tags: c, event-handling, sdl-2

I have a simple program in C using SDL2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
      "Hello, SDL2!",
      SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
      200, 400,
      SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
  );

  if (window == NULL) {
    const char* error_message = SDL_GetError();
    printf("error creating window: %s\n", error_message);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  }

  SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  if (surface == NULL) {
    const char* error_message = SDL_GetError();
    printf("surface is NULL. error: %s\n", error_message);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  }

  if (SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0, 255, 0)) != 0) {
    const char* error_message = SDL_GetError();
    printf("FillRect failed. error: %s\n", error_message);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window) != 0) {
    const char* error_message = SDL_GetError();
    printf("UpdateWindowSurface failed. error: %s\n", error_message);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  }

  SDL_Delay(2000);

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

On first launch, I've seen a window with green background but after that on every launch window is fully transparent and no error is reported. That's what I see:
[image]

It's not actually transparent, it just takes pixels behind the window as its background. That's what happens if I move it a bit:

[image]

I've also tried to rewrite the same code in other programming language (Zig) and behavior was the same: on first launch I've seen a green window again, but on every next launch it was buggy in the same manner.

My system is Archlinux, and desktop is KDE/Plasma on X11. What could be the reason for such behavior?

**UPD:** Adding an event loop didn't help the situation.

Comment: Some platforms don't draw properly without an event loop, and you'll need it sooner or later anyway. Go read about `SDL_PollEvent()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know about event loop and how to implement it but I'm interested of a reason why this happens and why this doesn't happen on first launch. So is it a known issue?

Comment: I haven't seen this exact behavior before (different behavior after restarting), but I did see a window not rendering things without an event loop. I don't think this is a SDL2 bug per se.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sadly, adding simple event loop with only SDL_QUIT processing didn't change anything except window doesn't now close automatically after 2 seconds.

Comment: Are you redrawing in the event loop?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No. Should I redraw independently on event received or is there something like WM_PAINT in WinAPI?

Comment: If this is a game, you should redraw continuously, X times per second. If this is not a game, you can try `SDL_WaitEvent()` to block while there are no events, and redraw when `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` arrives.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, it helped. You can form the solution as answer and I rate it so you get extra reputation. :)

Comment: I think I'll leave it to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned in comment, there might be graphical bugs without event loop, and event loop has to not only exist, but also include updating the window surface.

```
SDL_Event evt;
while (1) {
  if (SDL_PollEvent(&evt) != 0) {
    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
      break;
    } else if (e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
      if (e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED) {
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
      }
    }
  }
}
```